# the memory leak of use sparkstreamimg and sparksql with kafka in spark 1.4.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I used sparkstreamimg and sparksql with kafka, in my code have many sql query, I watch the gc recovery situation in spark driver,found that old gen increases very fast and full GC is very frequent, until memory leak,then the driver process shutdown; I analysis of heap memory,there are a large number of org.apache.spark.sql.columnar.ColumnBuilder objects, takes up 90% of the space, look at the source is HeapByteBuffer occupy,  i don't know why these objects are not released, had been waiting for GC to recycle. 
 In my cluster,I allocated driver 2g memory;If I want to run a longer streaming program, can only increase driver memory, but I think this is not a reasonable way, the memory will eventually be filled can not be released, only to restart the driver program; Can someone tell me why? Is my program has a problem or what? 
   my code is here:

```
object LogAnalyzerStreamingSQL { 


      def main(args: Array[String]) { 
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Log Analyzer Streaming in Scala") 
        val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf) 

        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
        import sqlContext.implicits._ 

        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, 30) 
        val topicSet = Set("applogs") 
        val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]( 
        "metadata.broker.list" -> "192.168.100.1:9092,192.168.100.2:9092,192.168.100.3:9092", 
        "group.id" -> "app_group", 
        "serializer.class" -> "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder") 
        val kafkaStream= KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,kafkaParams,topics) 
         kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => { 
            if (!rdd.isEmpty()) { 
              val jsonRdd=rdd.map(x=>x._2) 
              val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRdd) 
              df.registerTempTable("applogs") 
              sqlContext.cacheTable("applogs") 

            // Calculate statistics based on the content size. 
            val contentSizeStats = sqlContext 
              .sql("SELECT SUM(contentSize), COUNT(*), MIN(contentSize), MAX(contentSize) FROM applogs") 
             .show() 


            // Compute Response Code to Count. 
            val responseCodeToCount = sqlContext 
              .sql("SELECT responseCode, COUNT(*) FROM applogs GROUP BY responseCode") 
              .map(row => (row.getInt(0), row.getLong(1))) 
              .show() 


            // Any IPAddress that has accessed the server more than 10 times. 
            val ipAddresses =sqlContext 
              .sql("SELECT ipAddress, COUNT(*) AS total FROM applogs GROUP BY ipAddress HAVING total > 10") 
              .map(row => row.getString(0)) 
              .take(100) 


            val topEndpoints = sqlContext 
              .sql("SELECT endpoint, COUNT(*) AS total FROM applogs GROUP BY endpoint ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10") 
              .map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getLong(1))) 
              .show() 

              //....a lot of sql like that 

              sqlContext.uncacheTable("applogs") 
          } 
        }) 

        ssc.start() 
        ssc.awaitTermination() 
      } 
    }
```

jstat info:

```
     $ ./jstat -gcutil 48004 5000
      S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
      0.00   0.00  98.87 100.00  27.03  18337  137.051  1948 1724.113 1861.164
      0.00   0.00  99.51 100.00  27.03  18337  137.051  1950 1726.043 1863.094
      0.00   0.00  46.40 100.00  27.02  18337  137.051  1951 1729.225 1866.276
      0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  27.02  18337  137.051  1953 1730.202 1867.253
      0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  27.02  18337  137.051  1956 1735.058 1872.110
      0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  27.02  18337  137.051  1959 1739.521 1876.572
      0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  27.02  18337  137.051  1962 1743.700 1880.751
      0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  27.02  18337  137.051  1964 1745.484 1882.535
      0.00   0.00  63.82 100.00  27.02  18338  137.434  1965 1748.976 1886.409
      0.00   0.00  65.91 100.00  27.02  18338  137.434  1967 1751.125 1888.558
      0.00   0.00 100.00 100.00  27.02  18338  137.434  1970 1753.688 1891.122
      0.00   0.00  99.82 100.00  27.02  18338  137.434  1975 1759.191 1896.625
      0.00   0.00  13.42 100.00  27.02  18338  137.434  1977 1762.786 1900.220
```

Analysis of heap memory img: 
    [enter image description here][2]
    [enter image description here][3]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uP16.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeqKR.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxW4m.jpg
```